# How to define weight decay for individual layers in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow

In CUDA ConvNet, we can write something like this ([source](https://code.google.com/p/cuda-convnet/wiki/LayerParams)) for each layer:

```
[conv32]
epsW=0.001
epsB=0.002
momW=0.9
momB=0.9
wc=0
```

where `wc=0` refers to the L2 weight decay.

How can the same be achieved in TensorFlow?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can add all the variables you want to add weight decay to, to a collection name 'variables' and then you calculate the L2 norm weight decay for the whole collection.

```
  # Create your variables
  weights = tf.get_variable('weights', collections=['variables'])

  with tf.variable_scope('weights_norm') as scope:
    weights_norm = tf.reduce_sum(
      input_tensor = WEIGHT_DECAY_FACTOR*tf.pack(
          [tf.nn.l2_loss(i) for i in tf.get_collection('weights')]
      ),
      name='weights_norm'
  )

  # Add the weight decay loss to another collection called losses
  tf.add_to_collection('losses', weights_norm)

  # Add the other loss components to the collection losses     
  # ...

  # To calculate your total loss
  tf.add_n(tf.get_collection('losses'), name='total_loss')
```

Comment: Is this weight decay equivalent to the weight decay of alexnet?

Comment: Note, starting with tensorflow v1.0 `tf.pack` in line 6 of the example was renamed to `tf.stack`.

Comment: it should be `tf.get_collection('variables')` instead of `tf.get_collection('weights')`

Comment: Wouldn't tf.reduce_mean make more sense than sum? Then the weight decay will be (more) invariant wrt network size

Comment: This is wrong for any other optimizer than pure SGD. The L2-regularization in the loss is *not* the same as weight-decay (as in cuda-convnet and caffe) when momentum and other history-keeping optimizers are used. Weight-decay shrinks the weights by a relative amount after every update, this does something else when combined e.g. with momentum.

Answer (score 9):

```
get_variable(
name,
shape=None,
dtype=None,
initializer=None,
regularizer=None,
trainable=True,
collections=None,
caching_device=None,
partitioner=None,
validate_shape=True,
use_resource=None,
custom_getter=None)
```

This is the usage of tensorflow function `get_variable`. You can easily specify the regularizer to do weight decay.

Following is an example:

```
weight_decay = tf.constant(0.0005, dtype=tf.float32) # your weight decay rate, must be a scalar tensor.
W = tf.get_variable(name='weight', shape=[4, 4, 256, 512], regularizer=tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(weight_decay))
```

Comment: In the docs about regularizer argument it states ..."result of applying it on a newly created variable will be added to the collection `tf.GraphKeys.REGULARIZATION_LOSSES` and can be used for regularization." This does not imply that the loss is actually used, so we have to manually add it to the main loss which we minimize?

Answer (score 2):

Both current answers are wrong in that they do not give you "weight decay as in cuda-convnet" but instead L2-regularization, which is different.

When using pure SGD (without momentum) as an optimizer, weight decay is the same thing as adding a L2-regularization term to the loss. **When using any other optimizer, this is not true.**

Weight decay (don't know how to TeX here, so excuse my pseudo-notation):

```
w[t+1] = w[t] - learning_rate * dw - weight_decay * w
```

L2-regularization:

```
loss = actual_loss + lambda * 1/2 sum(||w||_2 for w in network_params)
```

Computing the gradient of the extra term in L2-regularization gives `lambda * w` and thus inserting it into the SGD update equation

```
dloss_dw = dactual_loss_dw + lambda * w
w[t+1] = w[t] - learning_rate * dw
```

gives the same as weight decay, but mixes `lambda` with the `learning_rate`. Any other optimizer, even SGD with momentum, gives a different update rule for weight decay as for L2-regularization! See the paper [Fixing weight decay in Adam](/https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.05101) for more details. (Edit: AFAIK, [this 1987 Hinton paper](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~hinton/absps/parle.pdf) introduced "weight decay", literally as "each time the weights are updated, their magnitude is also decremented by 0.4%" at page 10)

That being said, there doesn't seem to be support for "proper" weight decay in TensorFlow yet. There are a few issues discussing it, specifically because of above paper.

One possible way to implement it is by writing an op that does the decay step manually after every optimizer step. A different way, which is what I'm currently doing, is using an additional SGD optimizer just for the weight decay, and "attaching" it to your `train_op`. Both of these are just crude work-arounds, though. My current code:

```
# In the network definition:
with arg_scope([layers.conv2d, layers.dense],
               weights_regularizer=layers.l2_regularizer(weight_decay)):
    # define the network.

loss = # compute the actual loss of your problem.
train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss, global_step=global_step)
if args.weight_decay not in (None, 0):
    with tf.control_dependencies([train_op]):
        sgd = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=1.0)
        train_op = sgd.minimize(tf.add_n(tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.REGULARIZATION_LOSSES)))
```

This somewhat makes use of TensorFlow's provided bookkeeping. Note that the `arg_scope` takes care of appending an L2-regularization term for every layer to the `REGULARIZATION_LOSSES` graph-key, which I then all sum up and optimize using SGD which, as shown above, corresponds to actual weight-decay.

Hope that helps, and if anyone gets a nicer code snippet for this, or TensorFlow implements it better (i.e. in the optimizers), please share.

**Edit:** see also [this PR](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/17438) which just got merged into TF.